# Excel document-level customization - Adding worksheets

Tags: excel, customization

The Workbook comes with three sheets - Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3. How do I add another sheet, let the user add data and then save the data? I know I can use Sheet1.Copy or ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add to add but I cannot access the new one I added. Globals still has only three sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3) although deep inside the count of sheets is 4 just as ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count gives me a value of 4.
If the new sheets cannot be added dynamically, is there a way I can add sheets at design time so that they all work just like Sheet1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

You could add sheets via code as in [vba add sheets using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697706/how-to-add-a-named-sheet-at-the-end-of-all-excel-sheets).

You can access all sheets (including the ones the user added or those added by code) using a code as in [MS-Loop through sheets](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142126).