# 'workbooks.sheets.add after' not working

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to use a macro to add a sheet after an specific sheet. Let's say this sheet is named 102014. I want this macro to create a sheet after the 102014 one with the name 112014, but I can't use select or active sheet because it is actually part of a big macro and I switch back and forth between workbooks. Here is what I tried to do, with no success:

```
dim wbname as string
dim thismonth as string
dim lastmonth as string

thismonth = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells([address of a cell with the name of the sheet).Value
lastmonth = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells([address of a cell with the name of the sheet).Value

wbname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells([address of a cell with the file name here])
Workbooks(wbname).Sheets.Add(After = wbkname.Sheets(lastmonth)).Name = thismonth
```

The macro simply passes this last line and goes to the other one, no error, no nothing. As you  can see, I have a list with the sheet names and file names, and this is where I get the `thismonth`, `lastmonth` and `wbname` variables from.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697706/how-to-add-a-named-sheet-at-the-end-of-all-excel-sheets)

Comment: you need a colon after "after"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Add(After:= ...`

Note the colon that's needed.