# Renaming sheet in Excel with reference to another sheet, VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to rename my newly added sheet, by referencing to a value of a cell that is in another sheet. It looks simple, but it doesn't work.

```
Sheets("TABLAK").Select
Sheets.Add
Dim ujfulneve As String
ujfulneve = Sheets("MENU").Range("B2").Value
Sheets(ActiveSheet).Name = ufjulneve
```

It writes type mismatch error for the last row. Can you help?

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Name = ufjulneve` and you don't need the initial `Sheets("TABLAK").Select` at all

Comment: Thank you. I just wrote that line, because of the positioning of the new sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are correct and efficient but I wanted to add a little explanation as to what is going wrong with your code and why their code is the way to go.  One-liners can often seem mysterious and daunting as if they are too clever for their own good so understanding them well enough to use them effectively is essential to good coding.

The type mismatch error is due to the fact that the `Sheets()` function is expecting a `String` (the name of the sheet) but you are a passing it `ActiveSheet` which is a `Sheet` object.  Since it is already a `Sheet`, you can just use that and change its `Name` property directly:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = ufjulneve
```

But even better than that, Excel is very slow when it has to mimic the typical user interaction that you would take doing the same thing manually like selecting the worksheet before you reference it.  You should remove the following line altogether

```
Sheets("TABLAK").Select
```

because you don't use that worksheet after you select it anyway.  In addition, upon skimming through the code later, if you don't see/realize that `Sheets.Add` automatically selects the newly created worksheet you may the get the incorrect impression that `Sheets("TABLAK")` is the `ActiveSheet` since it was just selected 4 lines earlier.

Finally, unless you need to reference the value of `Sheets("MENU").Range("B2").Value` again elsewhere, you might as well remove it as suggested by the others, saving an additional two lines, leaving

```
Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("MENU").Range("B2").Value
```

Since this still refers to `ActiveSheet`, making it fagile in the face of later changes (what happens later if you mistakenly add another line between those two that changes the sheet selection?) then the one-liner is by far the best way to go:

```
Worksheets.Add.Name = Worksheets("MENU").Range("B2").Value
```

Answer (score 6):

accepting Socii challenge about maximum code semplification the *shortest* code is:

```
Worksheets.add.Name = Worksheets("MENU").Range("B2").value
```

Comment: I do like a good one-liner. Never realised you could set the Name directly in the Worksheets.Add function.

Comment: shortest is `Sheets.Add.Name = [MENU!B2]`

Comment: @Slai +1 for the shortest.  Plus that's a great illustration of the type of uncommon notation I was thinking of in my answer when I referred to one-liners sometimes being hard for many people to understand.

Comment: Thank you! And if i want to add some plus character to the b2's value? For example b2=abc, and i want to be it abcdef

Comment: Nothing, i figured out:)

Comment: @MátéBrunner, sorry I only see your comments now. But happy to see you already made it by yourself. BTW, if you used my solution you may want to mark my answer as accepted!

Comment: I haven't enough reputations to rate:) I'm new here.

Comment: @MátéBrunner, no reputation needed to accept an answer to a question of yours, just [click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @MátéBrunner: not! :-(

Answer (score 4):

The code can be simplified a lot by using a `With` block:

```
With Sheets.Add
    .Name = Sheets("MENU").Range("B2").Value
End With
```

See this post for further reading and a few more methods of adding a new Worksheet: [How to Add a Named Sheet at the end of all excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697706/how-to-add-a-named-sheet-at-the-end-of-all-excel-sheets)

Comment: This is an _Excel_ lent answer because it: 1)answers the question, 2)is terse, 3)stands independently, and 4)**Provides a link to a duplicate**, or in this case a related post.