# Add a new worksheet and name it from a user form's text box value.

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a new worksheet and name it from a user form's text box value. Please help. Thank you.

```
Dim CampDate As String

CampDate = RegisterCamp.CampDate

If CampDate <> "" Then
    MsgBox (CampDate)
    Sheets.Add.Name = CampDate
End If
```

Comment: Please look into this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20697790/7995847

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add a Named Sheet at the end of all excel sheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697706/how-to-add-a-named-sheet-at-the-end-of-all-excel-sheets)

Comment: What is the value of CampDate?

Comment: CampDate is the value of a textbox from a user form which is RegisterCamp in my case.

Comment: Yes but what is its actual value when it errors? There are restrictions on sheet names.

Comment: This is the error I get: Run-time error '1004 You typed an invalid name for a sheet or chart. Make sure that: ? The name that you type does not exceed 31 characters. ? The name does not contain any of the following characters: : ￥ / ? ＊ [ or ] ? You did not leave the name blank.

Comment: Yes really. Now I understand. I was so stupid. I looked at the error as to be an error in my code.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This Code works fine:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strCampDate As String
Dim ws As Worksheet


strCampDate = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

If strCampDate <> "" Then
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
  ws.Name = strCampDate
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What does Option Explicit do?

Comment: 'Option Explicit' forces you to declare all variables in your code. You can set in the options of the VBE. It's highly recommended, that yo use this option to avoid some pitfalls.

Comment: I receive the runtime error '1004' when a sheet with the new name already exists in the document. So you have to check this first before adding new sheets.

Comment: Are all run-time errors the same? I get this:

Run-time error '1004

You typed an invalid name for a sheet or chart. Make sure that:

? The name that you type does not exceed 31 characters.
? The name does not contain any of the following characters: : ￥ / ? ＊ [ or ]
? You did not leave the name blank.

Comment: If you'd mentioned that in your initial post this would probably have been solved 55 minutes ago!

Comment: Tell us what you type in the textbox.

Comment: Okay. So now I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `.Text`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim CampDate As String

    CampDate = RegisterCamp.CampDate.Text

    If CampDate <> "" Then
        MsgBox (CampDate)
        Sheets.Add.Name = CampDate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Still won't do mister.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Because it works fine for me.

Comment: Yes. Run Time Error 1004